# Creality Ender-3 slanted nozzle

Tags: hotend, creality-ender-3

I’ve just received my first 3D printer, the Ender-3 and while
assembling the unit I noticed that the nozzle is slanted and
not vertical on its holder unit.

[image: Ender-3 carriage with skew nozzle]

- Is this normal or do I have to try to make it vertical?
- Did I receive a faulty nozzle unit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not normal, the heat break (which is the cylindrical part between the nozzle block and the upper cooling part assembly is probably bent in your example) should be perpendicular to the 2020 guide beam (X-axis) so that the nozzle exit is exactly perpendicular to the (heated) platform.

You either received a faulty heat break, or too much force is exerted during assembly. You should contact the seller.

You could disassemble (after you contacted the seller) to see if the heat break is bent or something else is incorrect. Once you have the heat break out, you can measure the dimensions and order a replacement locally (for speed). It is advisable to have some heat breaks, nozzles, and even a heater block, heater cartridges and thermistors available as spares, these are pretty cheap to obtain through the regular Chinese vendor sites or auction sites.

If the heat break is bent, bending it back is not advised as this heat break easily tears open as it usually consists of thin walls.

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer.  It looked weird to begin with.  I bought it from Gearbest and I've just emailed them about the problem.

Comment: the heatbrakes can be replaced quite easily, but you'll have to get a replacement part.

Comment: I will disassemble it and have a look after I received an answer from Gearbest.  If its just the heatbrake that you would great.  Thanks

Comment: Please read [this transcript](https://textuploader.com/dyvl9) from Creality (!)

Comment: They have finally agreed to send me a replacement part.  Thank you for your help.